# How to show only error message in Laravel Validator

Tags: laravel, validation, error-handling

I want only error messages not the field with codes

**Controller**

```
 $validator = Validator::make(request()->all(),[
        'txtName' =>'required|max:25',
       ]);

     if($validator->fails()) {
            $errors = $validator->errors();
            return redirect()->back()->with('error', $errors);
        }
```

**View:**

```
@if(session()->has('error'))
{!! \Session::get('error') !!}
@endif
```

**Return:**

> {"txtName":["The txt name may not be greater than 25 characters."]}

**What I need:**

> name may not be greater than 25 characters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First instead of `with` use `withErrors`

```
 if($validator->fails()) {
            $errors = $validator->errors();
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors($errors);
        }
```

and in view

```
@if($errors->any())
     <div class="alert alert-danger">
          <ul class="list-unstyled">
                 @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                       <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                 @endforeach
          </ul>
      </div>
 @endif
```

Comment: Illegal offset type

Answer (score 1):

Use `@foreach`.

```
@if(session()->has('error'))

   @foreach($errors->all() as $error as $error)
      <p>{{ $error }}</p>
   @endforeach

@endif
```

Comment: it returns nothing

Comment: Try `@foreach($errors->all() as $error)` in your view

Comment: No. I followed the accepted answer it worked.